# Ubuntu 22.04.2 stuck then flick and then finally freeze

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, freeze, reboot

All started after the latest system upgrade: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Processor: AMD® Ryzen 5 5600u with radeon graphics × 12

Graphics: RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-35-generic)

Issues like Freeze and flickering happening to me quite often 8-10 times a day even more (sometimes within 7-8 mins after I restart)

After upgrade, one more issue I have started seeing is blacklisting and swap/crypttab issue

- blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
  I was having it after upgrade but solved by going into

```
BIOS > Secure Boot > Key Management > reset to Default Key Management
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustrated and tired of restarting the machine helped me debug more to find the root cause of this issue.

This looks only slack thing!

I removed slack from ubuntu snap.

and installed it as deb package from [official slack site](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/downloads/linux)

```
dpkg -i <path to downloaded slack binary>
```

FYI: Issue in slack software
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is no such documentation for the above issue.